# Include authorization header using fetch API POST method

Tags: google-chrome, safari, basic-authentication, fetch-api

Possibly I'm still not completely understanding all the ins and outs of browser security, but i think what I'm trying to achieve is relatively simple.

I have a page served 100% over HTTPS, I'm using basic auth, with the username & password being held by the browser and (should) be sent with every request from there onwards.

I have added the **credentials: 'same-origin'** to the fetch function call and for GET requests its included. but the same code path with a **POST** request does not include the header in the request.

```js
fetch("/center/57023368c4d6931600216494", {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Accept: "application/json"
  },
  credentials: "same-origin",
  method: "GET"
})

fetch("/users/find", {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Accept: "application/json"
  },
  credentials: "same-origin",
  method: "POST",
  body: "{\"center\":\"US testing\"}"
})
```

I don't think this is a CORS issue since everything is talking to the same domain. Ive tried expanding to **credentials: 'include'** but no difference. And I've seen the problem in both Safari & Chrome.

There seems to be little or no feedback so I'm really stuck as to weather this is a spec / implementation issue or a browser issue or a "your not using the code correctly" issue, any help appreciated

Comment: UPDATE: the code works as expected in Firefox & Firefox Dev edition. So this could be an implementation detail that isn't covered by the whatwg spec?

Comment: It very much seems like an implementation bug in Chrome and Safari. I would recommend reporting it against them.